# TypeScript: error assigning to optional parameter?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, puppeteer, lighthouse

I'm having trouble assigning a known type to an optional parameter in TypeScript.  In this case I'm using Puppeteer and the Google Lighthouse package.

You can see in my code below that the variable `page` (of type `Page`) is not accepted as the last parameter in the `lighthouse` function, citing error `ts(2345)`.

I'm new to TypeScript, so apologies if this is elementary.

```
import lighthouse from "lighthouse";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage(); // type 'Page' from Puppeteer: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page
const result = await lighthouse("https://example.com", undefined, undefined, page);
```

Visual Studio Code shows this error, and refuses to compile:

```
Argument of type 'Page' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Page | undefined'.
  Type 'import(".../node_modules/.pnpm/puppeteer@19.7.5_typescript@4.9.5/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/types").Page' is not assignable to type 'import(".../node_modules/.pnpm/puppeteer-core@19.7.5_typescript@4.9.5/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/types").Page'.
    Property '#private' in type 'Page' refers to a different member that cannot be accessed from within type 'Page'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: How odd I get a different error: https://tsplay.dev/N73BnN This one makes more sense since you forgot to use `await`.

Comment: oops, good catch.  I added the "await", but still seeing the same problem

Comment: If I add an await, then I don't get any errors at all: https://tsplay.dev/WoYqlN Maybe you have mismatched versions of puppeteer or lighthouse?

Comment: Hmm, that seems relevant.  Although I'm using matching versions, it seems that Lighthouse is getting its type definitions from "puppeteer-core", which is not the same as "puppeteer"